# How to mock the 'new' operator

Tags: testing, grails, groovy, constructor, mocking

I'm testing some groovy code that uses a java library and I want to mock out the library calls because they use the network.  So the code under test looks something like:

```
def verifyInformation(String information) {
    def request = new OusideLibraryRequest().compose(information)
    new OutsideLibraryClient().verify(request)
}
```

I tried using MockFor and StubFor but I get errors such as:

```
No signature of method: com.myproject.OutsideLibraryTests.MockFor() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Class) values: [class com.otherCompany.OusideLibraryRequest]
```

I'm using Grails 2.0.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second, optional parameter to [`MockFor`'s constructor](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/mock/interceptor/MockFor.html#MockFor%28java.lang.Class,%20boolean%29) is `interceptConstruction`.  If you set this to true, you can mock the constructor.  Example:

```
import groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor
class SomeClass {
    def prop
    SomeClass() {
        prop = "real"
    }
}

def mock = new MockFor(SomeClass, true)
mock.demand.with {
    SomeClass() { new Expando([prop: "fake"]) }
}
mock.use {
    def mockedSomeClass = new SomeClass()
    assert mockedSomeClass.prop == "fake"
}
```

Note, however, you can only mock out groovy objects like this.  If you're stuck with a Java library, you can pull the construction of the Java object into a factory method and mock that.

Comment: I was not able to find a single example on the web with class that has only constructor with parameters. Do you know how above example would look like for such case?

Comment: I am trying to mock `metricsHandler = new DeploymentMetrics(steps, env, docker)  metricsHandler.postMetric(team, service)`

Comment: If I try:
`def stub = new StubFor(DeploymentMetrics, true)

        stub.demand.with {
            DeploymentMetrics() {steps,env,docker -> new Expando(steps:steps, env:env, docker:docker)}
            postMetric() {a,b,c,d,e,f,g -> "from mock with proxy"}
        }`

I got `Cannot cast object '{steps=some, env={getEnvironment=vars.Testingq$_setUp_closure1@7cd65eb1}, docker=com.lesfurets.jenkins.unit.DockerMock@54dfe857}' with class 'groovy.util.Expando' to class 'spg.dora.cd.DeploymentMetrics'`

Answer (score 10):

I've just found that we can always overwrite a constructor via MetaClass, as Grails 2 will be reset MetaClass modification at the end of each test.

This trick is better than Groovy's `MockFor`. AFAIK, Groovy's `MockFor` does not allow us to mock JDK's classes, `java.io.File`, for example. However in the below example, you cannot use `File file = new File("aaa")` as the real object type is a `Map`, not a `File`. The example is a Spock specification.

```
def "test mock"() {
    setup:
    def fileControl = mockFor(File)
    File.metaClass.constructor = { String name -> [name: name] }
    def file = new File("aaaa")

    expect:
    file.name == "aaaa"
}
```

Comment: You may want to precede your test (or class) with `@ConfineMetaClassChanges([File])` which isolates the changes you make to `File`'s `metaClass`; see http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_confinemetaclasschanges